# Update array objects with a single array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having difficulty updating object values from a separate array.

Example:

```
mainArray = [
    { "name": "bob", "complete": "25" },
    { "name": "john", "complete": "50" },
    { "name": "mike", "complete": "75" },        
];

colorArray = ["#ff0000", "#00ff00", "#0000ff"];
```

I need to create a new Array that combines these values.

```
for (i = 0, ilen = mainArray.length; ilen > i; i++) {
    newArray.push({
        name: mainArray[i].name,
        complete: mainArray[i].complete,
        color: '',
    });
}
```

No matter what I do, I either only get #0000ff back or can't get anything working at all. Failed attempt:

```
for (j = 0, jlen = newArray.length; jlen > j; j++) {
    for (k = 0, km = colorArray.length; km > k; k++) {
        newArray[j].color = colorArray[k];
    }
}
```

Goal is to get back:

```
newArray = [
    { "name": "bob", "complete": "25", "color": "#ff0000" },
    { "name": "john", "complete": "50", "color": "#00ff00" },
    { "name": "mike", "complete": "75", "color": "#0000ff" }        
];
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Just set the `color` key of each person based on the index of the `colorArray`.

```
var mainArray = [
    { "name": "bob", "complete": "25" },
    { "name": "john", "complete": "50" },
    { "name": "mike", "complete": "75" },        
];
var colorArray = ["#ff0000", "#00ff00", "#0000ff"];
var newArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < mainArray.length; i++) {
  newArray.push({
    name: mainArray[i].name,
    complete: mainArray[i].complete,
    color: colorArray[i]
  });
}
```

Comment: That works, thank you. I still don't understand how JavaScript "loops" through my array of colors by index in this circumstance. What should I be looking at in documentation/references?

Comment: When you use a loop with an index like `i`, don't think about it as looping through the array, but think about it as looping through a series of values. In this case, the first time through the loop, `i` is 0, then 1, then 2, then stops because the comparison `3 < mainArray.length` fails. Knowing that `i` is 0, 1, and 2, you can see that you can access the first element of `mainArray` with `mainArray[i]`, but also the first element of `colorArray` with `colorArray[i]`. We just join the first element of `main` and `color` array, then join the second, etc.

Comment: @FelixGuo great explanation

Comment: I must have misunderstood how for loops work then. I appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

A more functional approach using `Array.map` and `Object.assign` looks like

```js
var mainArray = [
    { "name": "bob", "complete": "25" },
    { "name": "john", "complete": "50" },
    { "name": "mike", "complete": "75" },        
];
var colorArray = ["#ff0000", "#00ff00", "#0000ff"];

var newArray = mainArray.map((x, i) =>
  Object.assign({}, x, {color: colorArray[i]})
)
 
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an unnecessary nested loop below:

```
for (j = 0, jlen = newArray.length; jlen > j; j++) {
    for (k = 0, km = colorArray.length; km > k; k++) {
        newArray[j].color = colorArray[k];
    }
}
```

You may change it to :

```
for (j = 0, jlen = newArray.length; jlen > j; j++) {
    newArray[j].color = colorArray[j];
}
```